# Help with semi-controlled full wave monophasic rectifier using MOC3011 and SCR

Tags: power-electronics, rectifier, thyristor

I'm trying to build a full wave semi-controlled rectifier with this circuit: 
[image]

The zero's detection is working well and I am firing the TRIAC depending on the position of the potentiometer, the negative semi-cycle is doing what it must, it rectifies the voltage at a certain alpha angle.
However, the positive semi cycle has the same circuit and the same program for the zero detection and the firing is working well, but we obtain this at the SCR output: 
[image]

I don't know if that behaviour is because the circuit should be different for both semi cycles or if the SCR nor the MOC are burnt, we have already tried to change the SCR and it does the same thing, any ideas on what can be wrong? I am using two MOC3011 and two SCR tyn612

Comment: Have you tried reversing MT1 and MT2 on the offending MOC3011?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you, I found out that MT1 should go to the corresponding side of the source (just one side either Neutral or line) and MT2 should be connected to the Gate of the corresponding SCR, that way it works perfectly